# LXML cuts text at the first nested tag

Tags: lxml

Please have a look to this code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from lxml import etree
html_fragment = "<body><p>This is html, you can <a href='wikpedia'>learn more</a> on the wikipedia page</p></body>"

tree = etree.fromstring(html_fragment, etree.HTMLParser())

for x in tree.findall(".//p") :
    print(x.text)
```

this print :

```
This is html, you can
```

it cuts the text before the `a` tag. how can i get all the text of `p` tag ?

Answer (score 0):

find the solution: have to use .text_content() instead of .text

[official doc of lxml](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#html-element-methods)